# Reset "branch ahead" when using a bundle

Tags: git, git-am, git-bundle

In my current workflow, I get a git bundle, which I unpack:

```
$ git bundle unpack new.bundle code
```

and then I add patches to it:

```
$ git am *.patch
```

git log shows that the patches were committed; however, when I run git status, it says `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.`

From my understanding, it means that I have to push the comments to the original branch. It's not possible since I was using a bundle.

What's the correct way to go about it and commit to the current 'origin/master'?

Comment: You have two commits that your `origin/master` doesn't have. `git push` would be the way to push those commits to `origin`. What is your `origin`? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: Someone else bundled the code and sent it to me over email. may be the origin is the bundle. but I can't push the code into the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

> may be the origin is the bundle.

You can check that easily enough:

```
git remote show origin
```

> I can't push the code into the bundle.

I agree.
You could pull from the bundle though, which means you don't have to extract diffs from the bundle, but you can directly merge the last commits from origin in your repo.